# Benchmarking image enhancing algorithm

Tags: matlab, gpu

I have an algorithm that enhances images taken in low light and uses GPU for the computations. I need to benchmark the algorithm to see how many instructions or triangles it uses on a GPU?

Any ideas on how it could be done? Are there any performance meters that could be written for the GPU?

Comment: What's wrong with just measuring the elapsed time ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using NVIDIA CUDA for that then the NVIDIA Profiling tool that ships with the latest CUDA toolkit 3.2 will be the best way to profile every aspect of your app. I've written a small tutorial on how to use it: http://blog.cuvilib.com/2010/10/28/profiling-cuda-applications-on-windows-with-nvidia-compute-visual-profiler/